# Lazy constructed ArrayList with default emptyList for better performance

Tags: java, performance, list

Does this increase the performance if the list stay empty its life cycle?

```
public class LazyArrayList<E> implements List<E> {

    private List<E> list = Collections.emptyList();

    public add(E e) {
        if (list == Collections.EMPTY_LIST) {
            list = new ArrayList();
        }
        list.add(e);
    }

    // other necessary methods
}
```

For example:

```
List<Integer> deleteList = new LazyArrayList<Integer>();
for ( MyObj o : otherList ) {
    if (o.isOutdated()) {
        deleteList.add(o.getId());
    }
}
return deleteList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. ArrayList already has this optimization (in recent versions of the JRE). It instantiates its internal array only when needed:

```
/**
 * Shared empty array instance used for empty instances.
 */
private static final Object[] EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA = {};

public ArrayList() {
    super();
    this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so my LazyArrayList is useful if my Java version (Oracle Java 1.6.0_31) not contains this optimization?

Comment: My guess is that the cost of the indirections and the additional complexity will be worse than the tiny advantage you'll get by not instantiating an array. And Lists are rarely empty anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try with [ArrayList.trimToSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize%28%29) that says:

> Trims the capacity of this ArrayList instance to be the list's current size. An application can use this operation to minimize the storage of an ArrayList instance.

Look at [ArrayList.ensureCapacity()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity%28int%29) that says:

> Increases the capacity of this ArrayList instance, if necessary, to ensure that it can hold at least the number of elements specified by the minimum capacity argument.